# How to create a container in pymc3

Tags: pymc3

I am trying to build a model for the likelihood function of a particular outcome of a Langevin equation (Brownian particle in a harmonic potential):

Here is my model in pymc2 that seems to work:
https://github.com/hstrey/BayesianAnalysis/blob/master/Langevin%20simulation.ipynb

```
#define the model/function to be fitted.
def model(x): 
    t = pm.Uniform('t', 0.1, 20, value=2.0)
    A = pm.Uniform('A', 0.1, 10, value=1.0)

    @pm.deterministic(plot=False)
    def S(t=t):
       return 1-np.exp(-4*delta_t/t)

    @pm.deterministic(plot=False)
    def s(t=t):
       return np.exp(-2*delta_t/t)

    path = np.empty(N, dtype=object)

    path[0]=pm.Normal('path_0',mu=0, tau=1/A, value=x[0], observed=True)
    for i in range(1,N):
        path[i] = pm.Normal('path_%i' % i,
                        mu=path[i-1]*s,
                        tau=1/A/S,
                        value=x[i],
                        observed=True)
        return locals()

mcmc = pm.MCMC( model(x) )
mcmc.sample( 20000, 2000, 10 )
```

The basic idea is that each point depends on the previous point in the chain (Markov chain).  Btw, x is an array of data, N is its length, delta_t is the time step =0.01. Any idea how to implement this in pymc3?  I tried:

```
# define the model/function for diffusion in a harmonic potential
DHP_model = pm.Model()
with DHP_model:
    t = pm.Uniform('t', 0.1, 20)
    A = pm.Uniform('A', 0.1, 10)

    S=1-pm.exp(-4*delta_t/t)

    s=pm.exp(-2*delta_t/t)

    path = np.empty(N, dtype=object)

    path[0]=pm.Normal('path_0',mu=0, tau=1/A, observed=x[0])
    for i in range(1,N):
        path[i] = pm.Normal('path_%i' % i,
                        mu=path[i-1]*s,
                        tau=1/A/S,
                        observed=x[i])
```

Unfortunately the model crashes as soon as I try to run it.  I tried some pymc3 examples (tutorial) on my machine and this is working.

Thanks in advance.  I am really hoping that the new samplers in pymc3 will help me with this model.  I am trying to apply Bayesian methods to single-molecule experiments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than creating many individual normally-distributed 1-D variables in a loop, you can make a custom distribution (by extending `Continuous`) that knows the formula for computing the log likelihood of your entire path. You can bootstrap this likelihood formula off of the Normal likelihood formula that pymc3 already knows. See [the built-in AR1 class](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/blob/master/pymc3/distributions/timeseries.py) for an example.

Since your particle follows the Markov property, your likelihood looks like

```py
import theano.tensor as T

def logp(path):
    now = path[1:]
    prev = path[:-1]

    loglik_first = pm.Normal.dist(mu=0., tau=1./A).logp(path[0])
    loglik_rest = T.sum(pm.Normal.dist(mu=prev*ss, tau=1./A/S).logp(now))
    loglik_final = loglik_first + loglik_rest

    return loglik_final
```

I'm guessing that you want to draw a value for `ss` at every time step, in which case you should make sure to specify `ss = pm.exp(..., shape=len(x)-1)`, so that `prev*ss` in the block above gets interpreted as element-wise multiplication.

Then you can just specify your observations with

```py
path = MyLangevin('path', ..., observed=x)
```

This should run *much* faster.

Answer (score 1):

Since I did not see an answer to my question, let me answer it myself.  I came up with the following solution:

```
# now lets model this data using pymc
# define the model/function for diffusion in a harmonic potential
DHP_model = pm.Model()
with DHP_model:
    D = pm.Gamma('D',mu=mu_D,sd=sd_D)
    A = pm.Gamma('A',mu=mu_A,sd=sd_A)

    S=1.0-pm.exp(-2.0*delta_t*D/A)

    ss=pm.exp(-delta_t*D/A)

    path=pm.Normal('path_0',mu=0.0, tau=1/A, observed=x[0])
    for i in range(1,N):
        path = pm.Normal('path_%i' % i,
                        mu=path*ss,
                        tau=1.0/A/S,
                        observed=x[i])

    start = pm.find_MAP()
    print(start)
    trace = pm.sample(100000, start=start)
```

unfortunately, this code takes at N=50 anywhere between 6hours to 2 days to compile.  I am running on a pretty fast PC (24Gb RAM) running Ubuntu.  I tried to using the GPU but that runs slightly slower.  I suspect memory problems since it uses 99.8% of the memory when running. I tried the same calculation with Stan and it only takes 2min to run.